# What are the differences between RDLs in MS Reporting Services 2000 vs 2005?

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on a reporting project, and the client currently makes use of MS Reporting Services 2000, and I am developing using Reporting Services 2005.

What are the differences between RDLs in Reporting Services 2000 vs 2005?

The RDL is just an XML file, and the difference's I've picked up so far are:

1. XML Namespace in root element:
   2000:

   ```
   <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2003/10/reportdefinition" ... >
   ```

   2005:

   ```
   <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" ... >
   ```
2. **InteractiveWidth** + **InteractiveHeight** elements are supported in 2005, but not 2000. You simply have to delete these tags before deploying.

By fixing the above differences I am able to deploy reports designed in 2005 onto a 2000 server, with no problems.

Are there any other differences that you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable way to find a comprehensive list of differences will be to compare the RDL XSD for each edition:

[SQL 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa225747%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx)

[SQL 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154044%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Did a KDiff, and it works quite nicely - highlighting the differences. Luckily Mircrosoft have kept the XSDs fairly similar (ordering, naming, etc). 

There are many differences between the 2 XSDs, but I guess I was lucky enough to only be affected the 3 mentioned in my question. Guess I need to be on the look out for the others...